How can I autoscroll down a twitter profile page?
How can I autoscroll down a twitter profile page?
e.g.
https://x.com/potatosaysss
I know there's a javascript solution that can be done from the console, 'cos I did it many years ago, but I don't recall the solution.
I want to scroll down it.
The javascript would probably have to pause every 5 seconds or so, and scroll down each 5 seconds.
And then after a while it should reach the bottom of the page.
Then one could save the page.
I've done it in the past but i've forgotten the javascript that'd get the twitter page scrolled to the bottom automatically.
